# Receive data from app user swift

Tags: ios, swift

Preface: New to coding but have tried to do expensive research without finding anything that I thought would work---so please go easy

I am attempting to create an app that a user will fill out a form of multiple text fields and then when the submit button is touched, it will send the completed fields in an email to one specific email address.

I am stuck at the process of how to send the email with the data entered. I do not want to do this within the app with MFmailcomposer. Can I do this from a back end like firebase for example, or is there a better way to implement---or is this even possible? Hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction, I feel like Ive been stuck for weeks.

Thx

Answer (score -1):

There are services that will send emails for you (like MailChimp). They have an SDK and you'd have to integrate the SDK into your app. Or you could create your own API and call said API through your app and handle the email notifications in your API. Firebase looks like it has custom email options, but only for the Javascript SDK.